# E4X with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing, e4x, spidermonkey

Is there any way to get [E4X(ECMAScript)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/e4x) to work with NodeJS?

It would really help to output slick html/xml without hassle/noise.

It works fine using [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/spidermonkey) since it is natively implemented, but it doesn't seem to work with NodeJS.

using **node**

```
$node
> var name = "World";
> var p = <p>Hello {name}</p>;
...
```

using **spidermonkey**

```
$js
js> var name = "World";
js> var p = <p>Hello {name}</p>;
Hello World
js>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but I like to write NodeJS scripts in [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/), because you can use heredocs, or something like `p = """Hello #{name}"""`. 3 quotation marks also allows you to have newlines inside strings.

Comment: @Thai thanks for this it was good to know that there's something helpul like CoffeScript and actually is very clever, I like it a lot.

Comment: You can use React & JSX in NodeJS. But it's not exactly what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Node uses V8, which does not implement E4X as of now.

There's a 2 year old issue, but still active [issue](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=235&q=E4X&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20HW%20OS%20Area%20Stars) on the topic. But it has no real "status" nor was it assigned to anyone.

So in short: The answer is no.

Comment: yes, it is really a shame because at a first instance it is seems really weird not having this feature implemented...and it also seems there's lots of people waiting for it too :(

Comment: There are a lot of template engines that could be used to do what e4x does. The only downside is you'll need to run an additional call to put the variables into the template string after you've defined it.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a babel plugin that adds E4X basic support to NodeJS.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-simple-e4x

You can also use the npm simple4x library to parse xml strings to a XML like object.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple4x

The plugin transpiles the following E4X:

```xml
var fooId = 'foo-id';
var barText = 'bar text';
var xml =
    <xml>
        <foo id={fooId}>
          {barText}
        </foo>
    </xml>;
```

To the following JavaScript:

```js
var XML = new require("simple4x");

var fooId = 'foo-id';
var barText = 'bar text';
var xml = new XML("<xml><foo id=\"" + fooId + "\">" + barText + "</foo></xml>");
```